# Rings and main seal for Speedaire 1z945 air compressor

Tags: tools, air-compressor

I have an old Speedaire 1z945 air compressor that I'd like to put back into service. I can't seem to find a ring and main seal kit for it. I also can't find any technical specs on it.

Does anyone know how I can identify the right replacements for both the rings and the main oil seal?

[image]

Comment: A google search found this link, seems they might have parts.  https://mastertoolrepair.com/speedaire-air-compressor-parts-speedaire-compressor-pump-parts-c-545_565.html?osCsid=n1nooihd32p77l2083mlvq0stu

Comment: "Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories, internal combustion engines, **even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories**." Your answer is in another castle: [mechanics.se]

Comment: For seals on my compressor I use automotive gasket materials cut them out this works for me at a much cheaper price than the factory ones that are pre cut.